# How to suppress Outlook's security warning in win7-32 and Outlook 2003 that uses VB6 and CDO 1.2.1

Tags: vb6, outlook, cdo.message

We have VB6 code that works in Win XP and Outlook 2003 using CDO 1.2.1. Now that we moved to Win7 32-bit, we have the Outlook security warning (not UAC) that an application is trying to access a particular outlook feature. I have searched for hours without success. I am looking for specific guidance rather than corrections per se to my code. If you have particular code to display the address book in said environment, that would be great! BTW, building a homegrown list of addresses rather than calling the address book (thus requiring CDO) was rejected and hence not an option.  Thank you!

Comment: Well your right that it's the address book call which is upsetting the outlook security, you can either amend the exchange security (somehow I'm guessing this isn't what you want) or you can attempt to parse the offline address book file (**.oab**) which outlook stores on each user's computer and periodically updates (if running in cached mode). I looked in to it once but decided it wasn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Outlook Redemption to accomplish what you desire without the security warnings.

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm